# NodeJS, Passport & Passport-Local

Tags: node.js, authentication, passport.js, passport-local

So I'm running into an issue authenticating using a local strategy.  If I pass invalid credentials or anything unsuccessful, I get the appropriate error.  However, if they authentication is successful, then I'm presented with a 404 error.

I've dug around, and the best idea I ran across was dropping the session storage (which is where it seems to be happening, while serializing the user).  Anyone encounter an issue like this?

Here's some of the code, if you need any other sections of code, let me know I'll gladly provide it.

My Passport configuration:

```
var passport = require('passport'),
User = require('mongoose').model('User');

module.exports = function () {
    passport.serializeUser(function (user, done) {
        done(null, user.id);
    });

    passport.deserializeUser(function (id, done) {
        User.findOne({ _id: id }, '-password -salt -__v', function (err, user) {
            done(err, user);
        });
    });

    require('./strategies/local')();
};
```

My Local Strategy configuration:

```
var passport = require('passport'),
    LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy,
    User = require('mongoose').model('User');

module.exports = function () {
    passport.use(new LocalStrategy({
        usernameField: 'email'
    }, function (email, password, done) {
        User.findOne({email: email}, function (err, user) {
            if (err) {
                return done(err);
            }

            if(!user || !user.active || !user.authenticate(password)) {
                return done(null, false, { message: 'Authentication Failed'});
            }

            return done(null, user);
        });
    }));
};
```

All other methods work, I can query the DB to find the user, I have stepped through matching the hashed password with the provided password, it all seems to happen fine and I get a user at the end of the LocalStrategy (I make it to the final `done(null, user)`.  In the `serializeUser()` `done(null, user.id)` something happens.  I've tried stepping through it, but what I end up getting into seems fairly obfuscated (or I'm too dumb to understand it) so I can't tell what's actually happening.

Comment: It sounds like the call to `passport.authenticate()` may not be configured properly. Can you show how you're using that?

Comment: I'm not doing anything special there:  

    `app.route('/login')
      .post(passport.authenticate('local'));`  

I don't need to do any redirecting or anything, I just need it to return the user object back to the frontend.  

One thing that could be entirely coincidence, recently the node crypto `pbkdf2Sync` function started complaining that calling it without a digest was deprecated, so I added that in, and now I'm running into this.

--edit just tested that out, still get the same thing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your route setup:

```
app.route('/login').post(passport.authenticate('local'));
```

This will generate a 401 (*"Unauthorized"*) when authentication fails, but when it succeeds, there isn't anything configured to happen next, so you'll get a 404.

You should add an explicit "success" handler to your route:

```
app.route('/login').post( 
  passport.authenticate('local'),
  function(req, res) {
    // This will only get called when authentication succeeded.
    res.json({ user : req.user });
  }
);
```

Comment: In that scenario, the request object is `null`.  Whatever is happening in the `serializeUser()` is bombing out any of the data;

Comment: So I've done some more digging, came across `connect-mongo`.  I used this to store my session, in which, I found that the passport session is being stored...so something has to be bombing out inside `serializeUser()` itself (potentially after it makes the call to serialize the user info itself).  I'm digging around Passport's github to see if I can find anything.

Comment: There has to be something else shady going on, another project I have, using the same system, has quit working.  It was working just fine at the beginning of the week.  No package updates or anything like that...I may try this again on my home machine, see what happens there.

Comment: It doesn't make sense that `req` would be `null` (or do you mean `req.user`?). Did you log what `user` is in `serializeUser()`, to see if it makes sense?

Comment: So I dropped a log line at the beginning of `serializeUser()` and it didn't log at all.  However, in the callback function for `authenticate('local')`, I logged out `req` and `res`. `req` is in fact entirely null, and `res` is the user

Comment: If I take out the `authenticate()` callback, I get the log from `serializeUser()` which is the correct user

Comment: The code I propose is not passing a callback to `authenticate()`.

Comment: Sorry, not callback, the "success handler"

Comment: @DaveV the contents of the variables that you're getting (null, the user) suggest that you _are_ using it as a callback (`passport.authenticate('local', function(req, res) { ... })`), which is something entirely different (in fact, the arguments for that function would be `err, user, info`, which match up with what you're getting). It should be `passport.authenticate('local'), function(req, res) { ... })` (notice the parentheses after `local`)

Comment: Do I get the award for most oblivious dev of the day?  I totally missed the function's placement...

I swear I haven't NEEDED that there, but maybe I'm finally loosing my mind keeping up on all these projects...

Anyway, thanks again man!